# Get AppFabric Cache out of throttled mode

Tags: caching, powershell, appfabric

Hosting an AppFabric cache on the same machine as an sql server presents some known challenges, one of them being the sql server take up most of the ram and there by putting the cache in throttled mode.

When this occurs and I have freed up enough memory, how i put the cache in "not throttled state" again. Can't seem to find a powershell command to fit my need

Yes, I know it's bad pratice to host the 2 on the same machine, but those are the terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cache service detects there is enough memory to accept adds/puts, it will come out of throttling state, not controlled by user.
Here is the complete answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921030.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree that this is how it should behave - but or system will remain in throttles mode for hours - eventhough there are plenty of mem left